# Как правильно работать с циклами на js?

Tags: javascript, алгоритм

Есть код:

```
var str =  '123 \n name \n Описание первая строчка \n вторая строчка \n 3 строчка!';
var discription=str.split('\n'),
price=discription[0],
name=discription[1],
about=discription[2];

alert('price: '+ price +', name: '+ name +', about '+ about);
```

Так вот этот код в разделе about выводит нам только первую строчку описания, как сделать что бы выводились все строчки описания? Якобы что бы код все остальное выводил в раздел about?

Comment: чем не устраивает обычный цикл for?

Comment: Пробовал что то не получается у меня

Comment: предлагаешь угадать что не получается? :)

Comment: По этому и нужна помощь с кодом. Если можете напишите ваше решение как бы вы это сделали.

Comment: я бы использовал for. _По этому и нужна помощь с кодом_ - то есть все-таки нужно угадать что именно ты делал не так?

Comment: Я попробовал for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) { } и вместо цифры 2 поставил [i]

Comment: весь необходимый код с объяснениями - почему он не подходит, нужно добавить в сам вопрос

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Вместо цикла, можно использовать [метод match](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) и разбить строку сразу на три элемента, например так:

```js
var str = '123 \n name \n Описание первая строчка \n вторая строчка \n 3 строчка!';
discription = str.match(/^(.+?)\s+(.+?)\s+([\S\s]+?)$/);

var price = discription[1],
  name = discription[2],
  about = discription[3];

document.getElementById('n').innerHTML = name;
document.getElementById('p').innerHTML = price;
document.getElementById('a').innerHTML = about;
```

```css
#n,
#p,
#a {
  border: 1px solid;
}
#n {
  border-color: green;
}
#p {
  border-color: red;
}
#a {
  border-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="n"></div>
<div id="p"></div>
<pre id="a"></pre>
```

Либо после разбития массива по строкам, получить массив элементов начиная с третьего, с помощью [метода slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) и объединить их в строку с помощью [join](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)

```js
var str = '123 \n name \n Описание первая строчка \n вторая строчка \n 3 строчка!';
discription = str.split('\n');

var price = discription[0],
  name = discription[1],
  about = discription.slice(2).join('\n');

document.getElementById('n').innerHTML = name;
document.getElementById('p').innerHTML = price;
document.getElementById('a').innerHTML = about;
```

```css
#n,
#p,
#a {
  border: 1px solid;
}
#n {
  border-color: green;
}
#p {
  border-color: red;
}
#a {
  border-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="n"></div>
<div id="p"></div>
<pre id="a"></pre>
```

Либо все-так воспользоваться циклом:

```js
var str = '123 \n name \n Описание первая строчка \n вторая строчка \n 3 строчка!';
discription = str.split('\n');

var price = discription[0],
  name = discription[1],
  about = '';

for (var i = 2; i < discription.length; i++) about += discription[i];

document.getElementById('n').innerHTML = name;
document.getElementById('p').innerHTML = price;
document.getElementById('a').innerHTML = about;
```

```css
#n,
#p,
#a {
  border: 1px solid;
}
#n {
  border-color: green;
}
#p {
  border-color: red;
}
#a {
  border-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="n"></div>
<div id="p"></div>
<pre id="a"></pre>
```

Answer (score 2):

Отвечая на вопрос, *как правильно работать с циклами на js?* привожу пример работы цикла, для вывода содержимого объекта:

```js
  var treasureChest = {
      goldCoins: 10000,
      magicalItem: "сапоги скорости",
      necklaces: ["рубин", "жемчуг", "сапфир", "алмаз"],
      openLid: function () {
        console.log("!!!!!!!!");
      }
    };
    console.log("Вы нашли: ");
    var list = treasureChest.necklaces;
    for (var i = 0, x = treasureChest.necklaces.length; i < x; i++) {
      console.log(list[i]);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for(var i = 2; i < discription.length; i++) {
alert('price: '+ price +', name: '+ name +', about: '+ discription[i]);
}
```

Конечно из вопроса плохо понятно что именно ты хочешь получить, но по моему это.
Конечно, я бы реализовал все совсем по другому. Для этого создал бы объект со свойствами `price`,`name`,`discription`, затем их заполнял. Соответственно в последнем свойстве лежал бы массив и уже его выводил циклом как и куда требуется.

**PS**
По поводу кода на [фидле](https://jsfiddle.net/xw35knrr/2/) Поправил немного, теперь работает.
Суть проблемы была в использовании `innerHTML`, он не добавляет а перезаписывает строку... Соответственно каждый раз в твоем цикле содержимое параграфа перезаписывалось и в итоге там оказывался последний элемент массива.

```js
var str =  '123 \n name \n Описание первая строчка \n вторая строчка \n 3 строчка!';
var discription=str.split('\n'),
price=discription[0],
name=discription[1],
about=discription[2];
document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = 'price: '+ price +', name: '+ name;
for(var i = 2; i < discription.length; i++) {
var text = document.createElement('span');
text.innerHTML = discription[i];
document.getElementById('about').appendChild(text);
}
```

```html
<p id="test">
</p><br>
<p id="about">
</p>
```

Comment: Да что то такое, вот попробовал не alert а выводить на страницу, и выводит в разделе about: "3 строчка!" а нужно что бы выводило все 3 строчки что то типо такое: "Описание первая строчка  вторая строчка  3 строчка!" Вот можете посмотреть я захостил код https://jsfiddle.net/xw35knrr/

Comment: Ну все правильно он выводит... цикл отрабатывает и последний элемент равен "третья строчка!"

Comment: мне нужно не последний элемент, а все элементы после цифры 2